# Can I send the DTMF tone while in live call

Tags: android, telephonymanager, dtmf

I am working on an dialer, I am facing problem in sending the DTMF tone while in live call. Is it possible to send the DTMF or is there any work around to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can send DTMF phones using your fixed line phone or cellphone, but if you want to automate the sending of these tones over a phone connection, it becomes difficult because most modems can only send DTMF to dial a number, but when the connection is made, there is no way to send these tones. Some GSM modems do have this featuresuch as the WaveCom and the Multitech GSM modems.

Comment: Hi Ashraf, I am asking from the android app. I am developing an android dialer in which I want to send the DTMF while in live call.

Comment: @Android_Developer I'm working on the same project could you find the solution for this?